# Handing value into Success function from AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

G'day all,

I'm trying to pass a value through to a Success var from the original AJAX call.

Here's some code :

```
function isJobComplete(jobGUID) {
   var data = { "pJobGUID": jobGUID };
   var url = '/DataService.asmx/isJobComplete';
   var success = function (response, jobGUID) {
       if (response.d) {
           //The job is complete. Update to complete
           setJobComplete(jobGUID);
       }
   };
   var error = function (response) {
       jAlert('isJobComplete failed.\n' + response.d);
   };

   sendAjax(data, url, success, error);
}


function sendAjax(data, url, success, error) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: success,
        error: error || function (response) {
            jAlert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

When the isJobComplete function runs, it has the correct value for jobGUID on the first pass through, but on the return to Success after the AJAX call, jobGUID changes to the word "success", with the double quotes.

How can I pass through that jobGUID to the Success function so I can use it to do more work depending on the AJAX response?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Simply remove `success` from `var success = function (response, jobGUID) {`...so `var success = function (response) {`, then go and read about variable scope in Javascript :-) . It will have the same value you passed into the function. The value you were calling "jobGUID" within the success function was the second response parameter supplied by jQuery, which happens to be the status text from the HTTP request. If it succeeded, then more than likely this will be the word "success".

Comment: Oh, and in the error function, there will be no "d" within response. Check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ to understand what is returned.

Comment: Note: I think the first comment should've been *"remove `jobGUID` from the success function"* - anyway, If you read the [documentation for the $.ajax success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you'll see that the arguments passed to this callback function are: 1: the result data, 2: request text status, 3: the jqXHR object -

Comment: Thanks everyone for your great answers - I feel like a bit of a dill :)  Should have seen that.